# The size of GridView keeps growing when using ViewPager (Android)

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I am developing an application for on-line shopping. Due to the big number of products that I have to display I have used a lot of categorization. One of the main feature that I am using is `ViewPager` with `PageAdapter`. In every fragment it's supposed to be different layouts. In one of the fragments I have used a `GridView`. The problem is that when I switch between pages, and I return to the first page the size of the GridView , the number of elements inside keeps growing repeating themselves. For example if I have 12 elements at the beginning, after I switch pages and then get back again it becomes 24, 36 etc.

Below is the code I used for this:

```
EbuyHomeScreen.class 

public class EbuyHomeScreen extends FragmentActivity {

    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi") protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.ebuy_home_screen);

        /** Getting a reference to the ViewPager defined the layout file */        
        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        /** Getting fragment manager */
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

        /** Instantiating FragmentPagerAdapter */
        EbuyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new EbuyFragmentPagerAdapter(fm);

        /** Setting the pagerAdapter to the pager object */
        pager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    }
```

EbuyFragmentPagerAdapter.class

```
public class EbuyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;

    /** Constructor of the class */
    public EbuyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    /** This method will be invoked when a page is requested to create */
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {

        case 0:
            EbuyFragmentLatest myFragmentLatest = new EbuyFragmentLatest();
            return myFragmentLatest;

        case 1:

            EbuyFragmentSold myFragmentSold = new EbuyFragmentSold();
            return myFragmentSold;

        case 2:
            EbuyFragmentSponsored myFragmentSponsored = new EbuyFragmentSponsored();
            return myFragmentSponsored;

        default:

            EbuyFragmentLatest myFragmentLatestDefault = new EbuyFragmentLatest();
            return myFragmentLatestDefault;
        }

    }

    /** Returns the number of pages */
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
        /** code for returning the title*/      }
    }

}
```

EbuyFragmentLatest.class

```
public class EbuyFragmentLatest extends Fragment {

    final ArrayList<EbuyItem> ebuy_data = new ArrayList<EbuyItem>();
    private EbuyItemAdapter customAdapter;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ebuy_home_fragment_latest,
                container, false);
        JazzyGridView  mGrid = (JazzyGridView)v.findViewById(R.id.ebuy_list);
        mGrid.setTransitionEffect(JazzyHelper.TILT);

        ebuy_data.add(new EbuyItem("http://www.ebuy.al/Images/dsc/8884_400_300.jpg","Fustan Glamour","2,500L [17.9 €]"));
        /*
            ** filing with data continues */

        customAdapter = new EbuyItemAdapter(
                container.getContext(), ebuy_data);
                mGrid.setAdapter(customAdapter);
        return v;
    }
}
```

And this is the last class EbuyItemAdapter.class

```
public class EbuyItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private ArrayList<EbuyItem> ebuy_data;

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public EbuyItemAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<EbuyItem> ebuy_data) {
        this.ebuy_data = ebuy_data;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return ebuy_data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return ebuy_data.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @SuppressLint({ "DefaultLocale", "InflateParams" })
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.ebuy_item, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.price = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.price);
            holder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.ebuy_image);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.name.setText(((EbuyItem) ebuy_data.get(position)).getName());
        holder.price.setText(((EbuyItem) ebuy_data.get(position)).getPrice());
        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.image,
                ((EbuyItem) ebuy_data.get(position)).getImageUrl(),
                R.drawable.loading);

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {

        TextView name;
        TextView price;
        ImageView image;
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried extending `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter`?

Comment: Yes, that was what  I tried, but there is another problem. In every page I get the data from the server, and when I switch between fragments from a visible one to an invisible one and back to the first one the whole process of fetching the data starts all over again.

Comment: You could hold the fetched data in an ArrayList outside the fragments. Also check for memory leaks with MemoryAnalyzer, the leaks can stop your fragment instances from being destroyed.